# what are all the ways to update windows phone tiles?

Tags: windows-phone, live-tile

Going through MSDN library and other forums, these are the ways to update the Windows Phone Live Tiles (afaik):

1. Using push notifications,
2. Background agents,
3. ShellTileSchedule (to update tile's background images only).

**Are there any other ways to do so?**

Actually I am working on an app that get a collection of data/updates (not just background image) to be shown on tile from a Websevice.
This data needs to be displayed randomly on tile.

Now looking back on the options I just have

1. <del>Using push notifications,</del>
2. Background agents,
3. <del>ShellTileSchedule(to update tile's background images only)</del>.

And background agent have limitations (500 updates per subscription a day(if I do not use SSL), 15 sec time out etc)

So I am looking for a better solution, if there is any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference this nice Build video at 3:05 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-206

[image: Notifications overview windows phone 8]

To update a Tile, there is:

1. Scheduled

   1.1 ShellTileSchedule http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
2. Push & Local

   2.1 Push notification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

   2.2 Local notification

So why is push notification no option for you? That seems the best option for a remote webservice.

The other option is to use `ShellTileSchedule` and have your webservice compose a bitmap. https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: the picture clears it all :), the doubts  that i had at the time of asking the question.

"So why is push notification no option for you? That seems the best option for a remote webservice." 
I forgot to write that the data from webservice was required to be modified by the application itself, so i had to avoid the MPNS route completely.

Answer (score 0):

These are the only options on Windows Phone right now.  Windows 8 has the idea of [polling updates for tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150587.aspx) which are very convenient, so I'm hoping those come to Windows Phone someday...